Switch-statements: void_func(); break; vs return void_func();
I noticed that in the case of calling one void function inside a case inside a void function, the word break can be replaced with the return of the called function, if the common function contains switch statement only (inviteToThePark_b(int)):
void inviteAlina() {
// ... 
}

void inviteAdelina() {
// ... 
}

void inviteToThePark_a(int a) {
    switch (a) {
    case 1:
        inviteAlina();
        break;
    case 2:
        inviteAdelina();
        break;
    }
}

void inviteToThePark_b(int a) {
    switch (a) {
    case 1:
        return inviteAlina();
    case 2:
        return inviteAdelina();
    }
}


Is there a performance difference between the functions inviteToThePark_a and inviteToThePark_b? Can compilers react differently to a construct in a function inviteToThePark_b? And how appropriate is it to use return instead of break in such cases?

I doubt there will be a performance difference, but do make a performance measurement to make sure how the implementation you are using deals with it.  "how appropriate is it to use return instead of break in such cases?" - That calls for opinions. I personally think it's fine. Someone else might think it's not.

@TedLyngmo - In C++, not in C.

Oh f... I was sure it said C++ :-D Wait a sec,, it did say C++

@TedLyngmo - It did. Somebody made a poor edit I just rolled back.

It's hard to imagine any optimizing compiler where there's a performance difference. This is the type of thing handled by the simplest types of peep-hole optimizer.

@TedLyngmo the tags have been switched. In C, MS VC complains.

@WeatherVane Yes, the tag is back to the original which I commented on. In C it's a no-go for all compilers I have access to.

Bottom line: Illegal to return void in C, permissible in C++, unlikely to see performance benefits one way or the other. If you absolutely need to know, benchmark it and be aware that such a benchmark only says something about your specific implementation on that specific platform.

As they do the same thing (from as-if rule point of view), compiler might produce the same code for both. So just a style issue, or possibly quality of Implementation (QoI) of specific compilers.

As many others has already pointed out, this is all down to preference. I think it looks nice. As for performance, I also don't think it will give any difference at all, no matter the compiler.

If there is more to inviteToThePark, I’m sure there will be a performance difference.
